# Scrape data from a webpage and store them in a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to parse different `names` ,`bubbles` and `reviews` of various restaurant names from tripadvisor and finally store them in a table named `webdata` in a database. There are two `functions` within my script: one for storing the scraped data in `MySQL` and the other for printing the same in the console. The scraper is doing its job just flawless. As this is my first ever try to store items in a database and print the already stored items in the console, I might not have been able to follow the rules of `DRY`.

I will vastly appreciate any modification I should pursue to make the script robust.

This is my attempt so far:

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"

def store_info(link):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "test123",
      database="mydatabase"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE webdata") #kick out the table if it already exists
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE webdata (name VARCHAR(255), bubble VARCHAR(255), review VARCHAR(255))")

    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)

        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (name,bubble,review) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(name,bubble,review))
    mydb.commit()

def get_data():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "test123",
      database="mydatabase"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in mycursor.fetchall():
        print(item)
    mydb.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    store_info(URL)
    get_data() #retrieve the data from that table
```

Answer (score 2):

- The database setup `mydb` should be in it's own function, or even just
  a global since this script is rather minimal.  There's no reason to
  duplicate this code.
- If `mysql.connector` doesn't, I'd look for a database connector that
  supports the `with ...` statement for connections and transactions
  (relatively sure e.g. sqlalchemy supports that).  Because you can
  always forget to call `commit` (or `rollback`), but with `with` you
  have a little bit less mental overhead.
- It's a simple script ... long term I'd worry about losing data that
  way.  Also why is it dropping the whole table instead of, say,
  `DELETE FROM webdata;` and only recreating the table if it doesn't
  exist?
- The `bs4` part looks okay and the insert too; I'd perhaps have some
  checks in there that you don't overflow on the 255 limit with the
  review (or the name I suppose).  Also some warnings around empty
  values might be good for you to debug / notice that something's off.
- AFAIK `requests` is a good choice, you might also want to check the
  status code though.

Okay, so long-term:

- To be more flexible, look at `argparse` or any of the command line
  parsing libraries so that you never have to edit the script in case
  one of the parameters changes (database connection, URL).  I'd keep
  the HTML querying like it is, that's usually not wise to put into a
  configuration unless it changes frequently.